# How to sort color segments by value within the 100% stacked bars rather than by value across all the stacked bars in Highcharts or ChartJs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, chart.js

As per the image (click on a sample image), I want to sort per column-wise (Min to Max) i.e, 2% - 4% - 4% -6% - 84%, and so on for each column, **i.e., the highest segment within a bar is placed at the top and the lowest segment at the base.** How can I accomplish this on ChartJs or Highcharts?

Sample Image -
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: But would you like to sort your data before the chart initializing which allows you to keep the colors per series or would you like to sort already existed points (how it is done in the demo from the answer to this question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sort this yourself by creating a custom function. Basically, you have to switch to `columnrange` on initial load and create a new series out of the others. Here is an example:

```
function resort() {

    function sort(dataL, dataS) {
        return (dataS.y < dataL.y ? 1 : dataS.y > dataL.y ? -1 : 0); //====> this is doing the main sorting
    }
    function label() {
        return (this.point.high - this.point.low).toString();
    }
    function tooltip() {
        return this.key + ': ' + (this.point.high - this.point.low);
    }


    var allSeries = this.options.series,
        colors = this.options.colors,
        firstSeries = allSeries[0],
        stackingMatrix = [];

    Highcharts.each(allSeries, function(series, sIndex) {
        Highcharts.each(series.data, function(point, pIndex) {
            if (sIndex == 0) {
                stackingMatrix[pIndex] = [{
                    series: sIndex,
                    y: point
                }];
            } else {
                stackingMatrix[pIndex].push({
                    series: sIndex,
                    y: point
                });
            }
        });
    });


    var stackData = [];

    Highcharts.each(stackingMatrix, function(stack, index) {
        var stackY = 0;
        stack = stackingMatrix[index].sort(sort);
        Highcharts.each(stack, function(point) {
            stackData.push({
                color: colors[point.series],
                dataLabels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: label,
                    inside: true,
                    verticalAlign: 'middle'
                },
                low: stackY,
                high: (stackY + point.y),
                name: allSeries[point.series].name,
                x: index
            });
            stackY = (stackY + point.y);
        });
    });

    this.update({
        tooltip: {
            formatter: tooltip
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'columnrange',
            data: stackData
        }, {
            data: []
        }, {
            data: []
        }]
    });

}
```

and then simply call the `resort()` function

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: resort
        }
    },
    [...]
});
```

**Working Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/mrAhmedkhan/jfh5r6ym/

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt support, and when I try to plot data with 0 or null value, it still gets plotted in the graph but  **I want it to ignore 0 or null and plot rest** , How can I achieve this?

Comment: This query is out the scope of this question but you can simply remove the zero and null before populating the array in series as High chart itself cannot do it. Please vote and accept if it was helpful.

Comment: please vote and you are welcome :)